# Problem handling failed call to pigpio

Tags: pigpio

I've written some python code using pigpio over a network. I have two questions I can't seem to solve myself:

- Can I change the timeout when calling the `pigpidaemon` with `pigpio.pi(<ip number>)`. Sometimes the computer I call is unavailable and the default timeout is very long.
- Can I prevent the below message from being printed on `stdout`?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Can't connect to pigpio at alll(8888)

Did you start the pigpio daemon? E.g. sudo pigpiod

Did you specify the correct Pi host/port in the environment
variables PIGPIO_ADDR/PIGPIO_PORT?
E.g. export PIGPIO_ADDR=soft, export PIGPIO_PORT=8888

Did you specify the correct Pi host/port in the
pigpio.pi() function? E.g. pigpio.pi('soft', 8888)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Perhaps check that the computer is "up" before calling pigpio.pi().  Try a ping or something similar.

Comment: I do two different tasks with these calls. First I scan the whole network for computers running pigpiod, there ping wont work. When I then know which computers run pigpiod I call them to control pins, there I could definitely use ping! Thanks! :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Try & Except fail to catch OSError](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71937/try-except-fail-to-catch-oserror)

Answer (score 0):

for second part of your questions- the answer is "No".

[see joans answer, in similar Q of mine](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71937/try-except-fail-to-catch-oserror/71942#71942)